# MySQL: SELECT after INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, select, insert, zapier

I have a simple table, containing memberIds for each Email.

```
CREATE TABLE `cu_members` (
  `memberID` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)
```

The table allows a new memberId to be created for each new email address. I'm doing this using:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cu_members` (email)
VALUES ("newemail@domain.com")
```

I can also do this using:

```
INSERT INTO `cu_members` (email)
VALUES ("newemail@domain.com")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email="newemail@domain.com"
```

The problem is that I ALWAYS need to return a record from the query. I know a normal INSERT doesn't return a record, but i wondered if a different SQL statement might do so.

Why... I'm using Zapier to update a database. They only allow certain queries using their inbuilt libraries and the query must return an array or record/s.

Note: I can't call an external library or right a procedure outside of phpMyAdmin.

Is there a way to return a record for the email I was trying to insert?

Something like...

```
SELECT memberID FROM
    (
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `cu_members` (email)
    VALUES ("newemail@domain.com")
    )
```

Comment: You cannot return a select result for an update or insert query, that's obvious. What exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Why don't you insert the mail and then add the following query: SELECT memberID FROM 'cu_members' WHERE email = "newemail@domain.com" ?

Comment: Use a procedure to achieve the same. Update the record and then fetch the  record using `Last_Insert_ID`.

Comment: @marekful I've updated the question to make the goal and restrictions a bit clearer. Basically, I need to return at least one record after completing the INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai By procedure, do you mean a stored procedure in the DB. I can't do it externally. If so could you elaborate. I'm limited to a standard query sent from an external location, namely Zapier.